# TemplateDoesNotExist at / error in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm new to Django, and trying to create my first project. I tried to resolve the above mentioned error, spent hours banging my head against the wall, but was unable to correct it.. Given below are the relevant files. I guess it must be a small thing that I am missing, but unable to pin point it.

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from datetime import timedelta

def home(request):
    if request.GET.get('type') == 'formdata':
        options = {'fruits': [], 'vendors': [], 'release_version': []}
        try:
            options['fruits'] = ['Mango', 'apple', 'banana']
            options['vendors'] = ['Amazon', 'flipkart', 'myntra']
            options['release_version'] = ['2015','2016','2017','2018']
            today = datetime.today()
            options['end_date'] = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            last_week_date = today - timedelta(days=7)
            options['start_date'] = last_week_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            return JsonResponse({'options': options})
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'An error occured while getting form data'})
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

The index.html is the template I want the urls.py to point to, and is in the templates/project_name folder in my project. I have also set the TEMPLATES_DIR in the settings.py. I wonder where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well it means that the template `'index.html'` does not exists. Likely it is `appname/index.html`. Although that depends on your template settings, and where you stored the templates.

Comment: Hi Willem. I have not created any app, the index.html exists in the templates folder, with templates folder being in the same location as the manage.py file.

Comment: Also, in settings.py file, I have set _TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')_ , and added it to DIRS too.

Comment: Is there anything else I can add to my post which would help you understand the issue better?